# Swift 4: how to implement codable protocol for json array of different types

Tags: json, swift, codable

Can somebody enlighten me how to implement `codable protocol` to swift structs, for the following json array of multiple types?

In the following json array of materials, it can be reflection object, video or note objects.

```
{
  "materials": [
    {
      "reflection": {
        "title": "3-2-1 reflection",
        "description": "please reflect after today",
        "questions": [
          {
            "question": "question 1",
            "answer": "answer 1",
            "answerImageUrl": "http://xxx"
          },
          {
            "question": "question 1",
            "answer": "answer 1",
            "answerImageUrl": "http://xxx"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "video": {
        "title": "the jungle",
        "description": "please watch after today lesson",
        "videoUrl": "http://"
      }
    },
    {
      "note": {
        "title": "the note",
        "description": "please read after today lesson"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with a `Material` that has three optional properties, this is quite straightforward:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let materials: [Material]
}

struct Material: Codable {
    let reflection: Reflection?
    let video: Video?
    let note: Note?
}

struct Video: Codable {
    let title, description, videoUrl: String
}

struct Reflection: Codable {
    let title, description: String
    let questions: [Question]
}

struct Question: Codable {
    let question, answer, answerImageUrl: String
}

struct Note: Codable {
    let title, description: String
}

let response = JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
```

Comment: you should read this doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: The other "harder" way is using enum - but you will need to implement Codable protocol methods for it, e.g. something like in [this example code](https://gist.github.com/rinold/120eefe1e4e5d0f9da5e106120f72216) (based on @Gereon answer)

Comment: thank so much @MikhailChurbanov (: your answer seems more precise but what's the difference though, why should use enum for this case instead of above answers?

Comment: @Gereon, what do you think about Mikhail answer?

Comment: It's perfectly valid. I would choose between the two alternatives based on how the `materials` array is accessed and how the code doing that needs to distinguish between the 3 alternatives. Enums with associated values can require some unwieldy `switch`es, my approach needs a series of `if let`s - I'd say its really a matter of taste.

Comment: alright thanks (: I am rendering the three material types into `uicollectionview` of the same page, i guess both approach are doable for it! and yes i m using `if let` to give the correct uiimage for each material haha!

Comment: Absolutely agree with @Gereon - it's all about usage and personal taste. As for me if it's something not too big and stable (in some way) I would choose the `if let` - if over-complication doesn't bring you benefits, then it's more harmful than useful. The `enums` on the other hand are imho better in complex dynamic (evolving) projects - for example if you add a new type to support - exhaustive requirement for `switch` statements would be a great help in automatically finding all the places where you need to handle it.